# Not showing image in Xamarin.CarouselView

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm using xamarin build an app which get image from webservice and bind to carousel view.

But I can't see the image showing.

This is my xaml.

```
<StackLayout HeightRequest="250">
                <cv:CarouselView x:Name="carouselViewImage">
                    <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding base}" 
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   HeightRequest="180" WidthRequest="100"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                </cv:CarouselView>
            </StackLayout>
```

This is my code

```
ImageSources = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var productViewData = new ProductViewData();
                return productViewData.GetProductImages(Product.id.GetValueOrDefault());
            });

            carouselViewImage.ItemsSource = ImageSources;
```

The base I binding to is ImageSource

[image: ImageSources variable]

Updated:

I try another way which create new class:

```
class ImageTest
{
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
}
```

And using foreach to create new list of ImageSource

```
ImageSources = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var productViewData = new ProductViewData();
                return productViewData.GetProductImages(Product.id.GetValueOrDefault());
            });
            var testImage = new List<ImageTest>();
            //Add this foreach 
            foreach (var imageSource in ImageSources)
            {
                testImage.Add(new ImageTest { Image = imageSource });
            }


            carouselViewImage.ItemsSource = testImage;
```

And change xaml

```
 <Image Source="{Binding Image}" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="180" WidthRequest="100"/>
```

And it just work. But i don't want this=(

Thanks for any helps.

Comment: What is the type of ImageSources?  is "base" a public property?  What values are contained in base - are they a fully qualified url?

Comment: @Jason ImageSources is `List<ImageSource>`  which get by using `imageSources.Add(ImageSource.FromStream(() => new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageBytesArray)));`

Comment: I don't think you can use an ImageSource like that - how are you originally getting the images - from a url?  Or you might need to save them locally to a file and then bind the path

Comment: @Jason i updated my question which i create new class and use `List<newClass>` which can just work like that

Comment: I updated about the "base" you just ask. And the image i get is actually byteArray of image and rebuild to image again

Comment: I may be wrong about ImageSource - but I still think you'd be better off saving them as files and referring to them by path

Comment: @Jason any other ways than that because the image files have too many and will take lot of space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment `ItemsSource` is `List<ImageSource>`. In that case the binding is wrong, this is how it should be done:

```
<Image Source="{Binding}"/>
```