# Binding base64 to Image

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to take the images that come from my database in base64string format and convert them into an image to show them in my CarouselView. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843494/not-showing-image-in-xamarin-carouselview) tutorial, but I'm not getting the images to appear on the carousel.

here is my code.

**view_model_main**

```
 private void carrega_dados()
    {
        ws_dados dados = new ws_dados();
        var lista = dados.dados_home();
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
        {
            lista[i].image_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(lista[i].imagem);
            lista_imagens.Add(lista[i]);
        }
        //carrega as imagens e seta na string
    }
```

**main_page.xaml.cs**

```
  private void adiciona_imagens()
    {
        var lista = view_model_main.lista_imagens.ToList();
        List<ImageSource> lista_imagem = new List<ImageSource>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
        {
            lista_imagem.Add(ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(lista[i].image_byte)));
        }
        MainCarouselView.ItemsSource = lista_imagem;
    }
```

**main_page.xaml**

```
<StackLayout HeightRequest="210" Spacing="0"   Margin="0">
            <CarouselView x:Name="MainCarouselView">
                <forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding .}"
                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
        </StackLayout>
```

If anything else is necessary, I'll update the question with more information.

**EDIT**: Added the function where I convert the base64 to byte[].

**EDIT 1:** I've checked the base64 that comes from the database and it is working, I can decode in the [decoder](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) just fine

Comment: where are you decoding the base64 data?  Have you verified that the decoded data is a valid image?

Comment: @Jason I eddited the question with the function where I convert the base64 to byte[].

Comment: My Image for some reason is getting corrupted when I try to read it from the databse.I'll check what is going on and update my question.

Comment: I've edited the question with more information.

Comment: you may want to try FFImageLoading - it has Base64 support - https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Data-URL-&-Embedded-Resources-support-(including-base64)#data-uri-support

Answer (score 0):

What is type `lista[i].imagem`? Is this byte[] ? If so, `lista[i].image_byte` will be string which is Base64.

Now, in general, if you need to use the Base64 string as an image, you need the below for an img tag.

In this example, "image/gif" is mime types followed by "base64," then your bindings which is your actual Base64 string.

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP8AAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=" />
```

Looks you are missing the Mime type and base64 in the source. Only by assigning a base64 string image won't load.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is not a web/html question - he is asking specifically about Xamarin Forms

Comment: @Jason -  I'm trying to explain to him that for an image to load "data:image/gif;base64," is required, he might be missing the Mime type and word "base64". I'm sorry if that doesn't work for him

Comment: again, your answer is not applicable to the platform he is using

Comment: @Karthikk lista[i].imagem its a base64string and i'm converting to byte[] which is lista[i].image_byte.